# What are the benefits of transferring an iOS app from one to another account

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I want to know that what are the benefits of transferring iOS app from one account to another.

I read apple doc, as per apple says:

> *The App must have had at least one version that has been released to
> the App Store.*

I have an app with version 1.0 on app store, Now my questions are:

1. Once my app is transfered to another account then what will be the effect on existing app on app store? Is notifications in the app are deactive or it will work correctly or not? What will be the impact of this on existing users who are using this app.
2. Is it possible that my app will be work (can be download from app
   store and function properly).
3. If I had transfered my app then it is necessary to use new certificates and profiles if yes, why?

   Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Contact Apple's iTunes Connect Team

No-one but Apple can offer authoritative answers to these questions. Please [contact Apple's iTunes Connect](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus) and they will be able to help.